# Remove the space between column name in MSACCESS dynamically

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have created a web application which uses Database as MSACCESS, one of the column name in MSACCESS is separated with space something like "Employee Name".

My c# code is failing and not able to read the column name which has space between two words.
I cannot change the column name as it was used by many applications.

Can i dynamically add underscore or remove the space in a specific column.

Or can someone suggest the best approach for this.

```
SELECT 
    Format([empdate],'mm') AS Month, 
    Sum([Time]) as MyTime 
    Format([empdate],'yyyy') as CurrYear 
FROM Table 
where empName ='" + AND ManagerName='XYZ' 
Group by Format([empdate],'mm') ,Format([empdate],'yyyy')
```

in the query say empdate is emp date and ManagerName is Manager Name - i am getting exception while executing in c#

Comment: are you reading column names or column data?

Comment: Can you use a query which aliases those column names to avoid whatever problems they're causing in your c# code?  `SELECT [Employee Name] AS Employee_Name FROM YourTable;`

Comment: I am retrieving column data based on column name say - SELECT  Format([empdate],'mm') AS Month, Sum([Time]) as MyTime   Format([empdate],'yyyy') as CurrYear  FROM Table where  empName ='" + drpdownstaffName.SelectedItem.Text + "'   AND ManagerName='XYZ' Group by Format([empdate],'mm')  ,Format([empdate],'yyyy') - in the query say empdate is emp date and ManagerName is Manager Name - i am getting exception while executing in c#

Comment: That would not produce valid Access SQL.  Your prospects for success will improve if you can start by building and testing your `SELECT` statement in the Access query designer.

Comment: @Dipesh - Please do not add code to a comment!  Edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: @Dipesh - after "as MyTime" I believe you need a comma.  And have you tried adding [] square brackets around the 3 column names that have embedded space? Did that solve it? tkx